# VBA code to add number in sequence and rows of data

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am converting an old 2010 Access data base to Access 2016, the database being originally built in Access 2000. My customer table used an **autonumber** field to generate a `CustomerId` number.

I used this field to connect to my repairs table which currently has 13,000 records. I have not been able to find away to maintain this field in new database, so I thought if I can export the table to an Excel file than add numbers in sequence of missing ID numbers along with data to fill name and address fields for temp import to new database, after import I can delete these fields.

I don't know if there are other ways to maintain this id. I imported customer table with Old ID field name, but access won't allow me to use this field to create relationships to new repairs table.

The ID numbers go from 1 to 8,437 yet there are only 7,884 records in the spreadsheet.

Comment: This seems like the type of thing you want to do in Access, rather than Excel. Have you tried making a copy of the table in question, editing the copy the way you want, renaming the old table and then renaming the edited copy to the original name?

Comment: You can't determine the value of an autonumber field. instead of importing the old data into an existing new table, import the old table as new table including structure and data. This is not a matter of VBA.

Comment: Gaps would be records that were deleted. You would hit the exact same problem if this were SQL Server with an `int` primary key with `identity` specification, which is pretty much standard and best practice. In SQL Server you can `set identity insert on`; not sure if Access has something similar, or if it lets you just insert values in an *autonumber* column.

Comment: So I asked around, and it appears you can use plain SQL in Access to insert into an autonumber column (the UI doesn't let you do it).

Comment: Just to add something - autonumber can have gaps if you start to insert then cancel. All the autonumber guarantees is that the key you get is *unique*, not *contiguous*. If you want contigous sequence, you need something else. I would consider using a tally table as a general solution for that type of problem. OTOH, if the numbers have meaning (and normally they should not!), they probably shouldn't be an autonumber to begin with.

Comment: @Olivier If I understand you correctly, that's just not true. You can determine the seed of an autonumber field using VBA. See [Allen Browne's GetSeedADOX](http://allenbrowne.com/func-ADOX.html#GetSeedADOX). Also, the `ResetSeed` function on that same page can be used to reset the identity seed after manually importing data (strongly recommended if you're going to do inserts in autonumber fields to avoid conflicts)

Comment: Yes, but you cannot import existing, non-contiguous numbers into an autonumber field.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resequence the IDs is to take advantage of "Cascade Update Related Fields".
What you will have to do is

- Delete all the relationships to your table
- Change the ID field to Number - Long Integer
- Add the relationships back, inforcing cascading updates
- Shift all the indices to a number larger than the current max ID
- Renumber than starting at 1
- Delete all the relationships
- Delete the ID field
- Save the table
- Add the ID field back as auto-increment - primary key
- Add the relationships back

[image]

[image]

### ReImcrementCustomerIDs:Sub

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReImcrementCustomerIDs(ByVal FirstIndex As Long)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As Database
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim ID As Long
    Set db = CurrentDb

    SQL = "SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerID;"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs("CustomerID") = FirstIndex
        FirstIndex = FirstIndex + 1
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

### Usage

```
ReImcrementCustomerIDs 50000
ReImcrementCustomerIDs 1
```